# Конвертировать выражение oracle t1.id = t2.id (+) без изменения FROM

Tags: sql, oracle

Появилась необычная задача переделать запрос sql Oracle типа :

```
 Select 
 * 
    FROM 
 table1 t1
,table2 t2 
    WHERE
 t1.id = t2.id (+)
```

Нужно сделать аналог без использования (+).

При этом менять область SELECT и FROM нельзя. Допускаются изменения только в where. Что-то светлые мысли как это сделать не приходят. Если есть идеи буду рад услышать.

Comment: *Допускаются изменения только в where.* Нерешаемо. Сервер не умеет возвращать записи, которых у него нет, а LEFT JOIN требует возврата несуществующей в таблице записи, у которой все поля - NULL.

Comment: грязный хак (но раз уж хочется странного, то и решение тоже будет странным), не уверен, что сработает из-за возможного несовпадения порядка колонок - заменить после WHERE на `t1.id = t2.id UNION ALL select * from table1 t1 left join table t2 on (t1.id = t2.id) where t2.id is null`

Comment: _Появилась необычная задача_, а какова причина появления этой задачи, "головоломка" или это действительно реальная задача. Если последнее, то пожалуйста поподробней, зачем нужно сделать аналог внешнего соединения без (+)?